# Express Vector.<T> in MXML

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

Is there a better way to do this:

```
<Area elements="{Vector.&lt;MyClass&gt;([N01, N02, N03])}">
```

`Area.elements` is a Vector of type MyClass, the elements I'm passing are other UIElements that are defined in the same MXML document.

My problem is that I have to use `&lt;` & `&gt;`, it's messy.

Is there a better way that I can do this, I would prefer to express it something like this:

```
<Area>
    <elements>
        N01, N02, N03
    </elements>
</Area>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it with a Vector; but following standard MXML conventions; I would expect it to be like this:

```
<Area>
    <elements>
     <Vector type="String">
        <String>N01</String>,
        <String>N02</String>,
        <String>N03</String>,
     <Vector>
    </elements>
</Area>
```

[Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f65f-7ff1.html#WS03d33b8076db57b9626da506121e50da8d4-8000)

Comment: The problem is that the UIElements that I'm passing in the Vector are already defined previously in the document. When constructing the Vector I need to pass them by reference, not create new instances.

Comment: You're going to be better off creating a Vector in ActionScript.  I think if you use the 'object' tag in MXML; a new object in is created.  I think you can create a new object and pass in your reference as a property on that object.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll keep it the way it is for now then.

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var myVector:Vector.<MyClass> = new <MyClass>[N01,N02,N03];
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<Area elements="{myVector}">
```

I know you specified MXML, but this is pretty light.

Comment: I did consider this but I thought it could get messy also. There are around 200 of these Vectors and each one forms a link between a `UIElement` and other `UIElement`s in the same view. I thought it would be tidier to keep them next to the related element.

Comment: For now I have done them all in the same way that I posted, it's not that bad I suppose.

Comment: If you have 200 different vectors you're explicitly hard-coding, that does sound pretty messy.  You might want to consider some kind of factory to generate them.  I know nothing about your specifics but that sounds unmanageable.

Comment: Yeah, I would love to, but it's for an image map. The vectors contain the different points in the map, and the image has no logical layout so it's much easier just to hard code.